# Why not "ADD TO CART" button not rendering the item into the cart from JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've managed to setup the HTML and JS functionality of what the cart should do as each button is clicked. My problem is that the JS is not rendering the cart items when the shop item is clicked and I can't figure out why.

My HTML does use Tailwind as it's styling.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

HTML

```
<!-- nav bar -->
    <nav class="bg-white sticky top-0 shadow-lg flex items-center h-16 w-full">
        <div class="w-full flex items-center justify-between px-20">
            <h2 class="text-2xl font-semibold text-gray-600">Shop<span class="text-red-200">Better</span></h2>
            <div class="relative cursor-pointer cart-btn">
                <i class="fas fa-cart-plus text-2xl text-gray-600"></i>
                <div class="absolute left-4 bottom-4 bg-red-200 text-white px-2 rounded-md cart-items">0</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Hero section -->
    <section class="p-6">
        <div>
            <h1>Shopping</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Debitis sequi deserunt doloremque?
                Necessitatibus velit eos exercitationem molestias porro eveniet blanditiis sunt nam autem dolore,
                doloremque alias expedita neque provident harum?</p>
            <input type="Search for an item...">
            <button>Search</button>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Shopping section -->
    <section class="bg-red-200 text-center content-section">
        <div class="p-16 text-5xl font-bold text-gray-600">
            <h2>Products</h2>
        </div>

        <div
            class="px-32 py-16 grid row-auto gap-10 grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 xl:grid-cols-3 2xl:grid-cols-4 shop-items">

            <div class="bg-white rounded-lg shop-item">
                <img class="rounded-md w-screen object-cover max-h-60 shop-item-image"
                    src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1055270/pexels-photo-1055270.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260">
                <div class="py-2 px-8 text-gray-600 shop-item-details">
                    <span class="text-left shop-item-title">Cream</span>
                    <span class="text-right shop-item-price">$12.99</span>
                    <button
                        class="bg-purple-200 font-bold px-3 mt-2 text-xl py-4 mb-4 w-full rounded-md transition-all hover:bg-purple-300 btn btn-primary shop-item-button"
                        type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bg-white rounded-lg shop-item">
                <img class="rounded-md w-screen object-cover max-h-60 shop-item-image"
                    src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1055271/pexels-photo-1055271.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260">
                <div class="py-2 px-8 text-gray-60 shop-item-details">
                    <span class="text-left shop-item-title">Frosting</span>
                    <span class="text-right shop-item-price">$14.99</span>
                    <button
                        class="bg-purple-200 font-bold px-3 mt-2 text-xl py-4 mb-4 w-full rounded-md transition-all hover:bg-purple-300 btn btn-primary shop-item-button"
                        type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bg-white rounded-lg shop-item">
                <img class="rounded-md w-screen object-cover max-h-60 shop-item-image"
                    src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1055271/pexels-photo-1055271.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260">
                <div class="py-2 px-8 text-gray-60 shop-item-details">
                    <span class="text-left shop-item-title">Frosting</span>
                    <span class="text-right shop-item-price">$14.99</span>
                    <button
                        class="bg-purple-200 font-bold px-3 mt-2 text-xl py-4 mb-4 w-full rounded-md transition-all hover:bg-purple-300 btn btn-primary shop-item-button"
                        type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bg-white rounded-lg shop-item">
                <img class="rounded-md w-screen object-cover max-h-60 shop-item-image"
                    src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3081657/pexels-photo-3081657.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260">
                <div class="py-2 px-8 text-gray-60 shop-item-details">
                    <span class="text-left shop-item-title">Berry</span>
                    <span class="text-right shop-item-price">$9.99</span>
                    <button
                        class="bg-purple-200 font-bold px-3 mt-2 text-xl py-4 mb-4 w-full rounded-md transition-all hover:bg-purple-300 btn btn-primary shop-item-button"
                        type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bg-white rounded-lg shop-item">
                <img class="rounded-md w-screen object-cover max-h-60 shop-item-image"
                    src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1998634/pexels-photo-1998634.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260">
                <div class="py-2 px-8 text-gray-60 shop-item-details">
                    <span class="text-left shop-item-title">Deluxe</span>
                    <span class="text-right shop-item-price">$19.99</span>
                    <button
                        class="bg-purple-200 font-bold px-3 mt-2 text-xl py-4 mb-4 w-full rounded-md transition-all hover:bg-purple-300 btn btn-primary shop-item-button"
                        type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bg-white rounded-lg shop-item">
                <img class="rounded-md w-screen object-cover max-h-60 shop-item-image"
                    src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/783274/pexels-photo-783274.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260">
                <div class="py-2 px-8 text-gray-60 shop-item-details">
                    <span class="text-left shop-item-title">Oreo</span>
                    <span class="text-right shop-item-price">$19.99</span>
                    <button
                        class="bg-purple-200 font-bold px-3 mt-2 text-xl py-4 mb-4 w-full rounded-md transition-all hover:bg-purple-300 btn btn-primary shop-item-button"
                        type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="text-center content-section">
        <h2 class="p-16 text-5xl font-bold text-gray-600 section-header">CART</h2>
        <div class="px-32 py-16 grid row-auto gap-10 grid-cols-3 cart-row">
            <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">ITEM</span>
            <span class="cart-price cart-header cart-column">PRICE</span>
            <span class="cart-quantity cart-header cart-column">QUANTITY</span>
        </div>

        <div class="cart-items">
        </div>

        <div class="cart-total">
            <strong class="cart-total-title">Total</strong>
            <span class="cart-total-price">$0</span>
        </div>
        <button
            class="bg-green-200 font-bold px-3 mt-2 text-xl py-4 mb-4 w-full rounded-md transition-all hover:bg-green-300 btn btn-primary btn-purchase"
            type="button">PURCHASE</button>
    </section>

    <script src="./JS/app.js"></script>
```

JavaScript

```
function ready() {
    let removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger');
    for (let i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
        let button = removeCartItemButtons[i];
        button.addEventListener('click', removeCartItem);
    }

    let quantityInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input');
    for (let i = 0; i < quantityInputs.length; i++) {
        let input = quantityInputs[i];
        input.addEventListener('change', quantityChanged);
    }

    let addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-button');
    for (let i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
        let button = addToCartButtons[i];
        button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked);
    }

    document.getElementsByClassName('btn-purchase')[0].addEventListener('click', purchaseClicked);
}

function purchaseClicked() {
    alert('Thank you for your purchase');
    let cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('.cart-items')[0];
    while (cartItems.hasChildNodes()) {
        cartItems.removeChild(cartItems.firstChild);
    }
    updateCartTotal();
}

function removeCartItem(event) {
    let buttonClicked = event.target;
    buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
    updateCartTotal();
}

function quantityChanged(event) {
    let input = event.target;
    if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value <= 0) {
        input.value = 1;
    }
    updateCartTotal();
}

function addToCartClicked(event) {
    let button = event.target;
    let shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement;
    let title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-title')[0].innerText;
    let price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-price')[0].innerText;
    let imageSrc = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-image')[0].src;
    addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc);
    updateCartTotal();
}

function addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc) {
    let cartRow = document.createElement('div');
    cartRow.classList.add('cart-row');
    let cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0];
    let cartItemNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('cart-item-title');
    for (let i = 0; i < cartItemNames.length; i++) {
        if (cartItemNames[i].innerText == title) {
            alert('This item is already added to the cart');
            return
        };
    };
    let cartRowContents = `
                <div class="grid align-middle grid-cols-3 gap-2 my-4">
                        <img class="h-28 w-28" src="${imageSrc}" alt="Product"/>
                            <div>
                                <h4>${price}</h4>
                                <h5 class="cart-price">${price}</h5>
                                <span class="text-red-200 cursor-pointer remove-btn">Remove</span>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="1">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">REMOVE</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>`;
    cartRow.innerHTML = cartRowContents;
    cartItems.append(cartRow);
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')[0].addEventListener('click', removeCartItem);
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0].addEventListener('change', quantityChanged);
}

function updateCartTotal() {
    let cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0];
    let cartRows = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row');
    let total = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
        let cartRow = cartRows[i];
        let priceElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0];
        let quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0];
        let price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('$', ''));
        let quantity = quantityElement.value;
        total = total + (price * quantity);
    }
    total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100;
    document.getElementsByClassName('cart-total-price')[0].innerText = '$' + total;
}

ready();
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. Unless I'm not doing something right

Comment: Can you minimize your given code into a series of snippets that can walk us through the functionality you are aiming for? It would be better if you can arrange them into steps until we get to the last step that has your issue. Providing a working source code, via https://stackblitz.com/edit/tailwindcss for example, would be great too. You may use Stack Overflow's [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) as your guide before publishing your question.